# Sqlite 3 select statemen

Tags: sqlite

I need to do a somewhat complex select in sqlite3 if you guys can help me?

I got a 'messages' table holding the following fields:

```
from | to | message_text | message_timestamp
```

and the rows:

```
a | b | Hi | 101
a | b | How are you? | 103
b | a | Fine,thanks | 104
c | a | Hey dude! | 115
a | b | I need to tell you something. | 1102
d | b | Yo dude | 1234
b | d | Yea dude, whatsup? | 1443
```

I'd like to select the last messages from the above conversation in chronologic order by disregarding if the message was sent form x to y or form y to x, the xy or yx pair should be taken into account. So for the example above, you'd get something like this:

```
b | d | Yea dude, whatsup? | 1443
a | b | I need to tell you something. | 1102
c | a | Hey dude! | 115
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Just looking into GroupBy clause. Looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick which works here to use the scalar min/max trick to collect records sharing the same from/to or to/from pairs into the same logical group.  In the query below, the innermost subquery buckets would collect, for example, from `b` to `d` into the same bucket as from `d` to `b`.  Then we aggregate over this to find the latest timestamp, and finally join back to your original table to retrieve the entire rows you want.

```
SELECT
    m1.*
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        t."from",
        t."to",
        MAX(t.message_timestamp) AS max_ts
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MIN("from", "to") AS "from",
            MAX("from", "to") AS "to",
            message_text,
            message_timestamp
        FROM messages
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        t."from",
        t."to"
) m2
    ON MIN(m1."from", m1."to") = m2."from" AND
       MAX(m1."from", m1."to") = m2."to"   AND
       m1.message_timestamp  = m2.max_ts
ORDER BY m1.message_timestamp DESC;
```

Note: Please *don't* use SQL keywords like `from` and `to` when naming your columns (or tables, or databases).  I needed to escape `from` in double quotes to get the query to work.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

(The demo is in MySQL since Rextester does not support SQLite.  The only difference is that `MIN` is replaced by `LEAST`, and the columns are escaped slightly differently.)

Answer (score 0):

Combine two temporary results, one with `from`/`to`, and one with `to`/`from`. Then filter out the duplicates by enforcing that the value in the first column is less than the second one. Then you can use a simply grouping over these columns:

```
SELECT c1,
       c2,
       message_text,
       max(message_timestamp)
FROM (SELECT "from" AS c1, "to" AS c2, message_text, message_timestamp
      FROM messages
      WHERE "from" < "to"

      UNION ALL

      SELECT "to",         "from",     message_text, message_timestamp
      FROM messages
      WHERE "to" < "from"
     )
GROUP BY c1, c2;
```

(Using [bare columns in an aggregated query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg) requires SQLite 3.7.11 or later.)